# sorting tuples in python with a custom key

Tags: python, sorting, tuples

Hi:
I'm trying to sort a list of tuples in a custom way:
For example:

```
lt = [(2,4), (4,5), (5,2)]
```

must be sorted:

```
lt = [(5,2), (2,4), (4,5)]
```

Rules:
* b tuple is greater than a tuple if a[1] == b[0]
* a tuple is greater than b tuple if a[0] == b[1]

I've implemented a cmp function like this:

```
def tcmp(a, b):
    if a[1] == b[0]:
       return -1
    elif a[0] == b[1]:
       return 1
    else:
       return 0
```

but sorting the list:

```
lt.sort(tcmp)
```

lt show me:

```
lt = [(2, 4), (4, 5), (5, 2)]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I see nothing wrong, except that given your input and comparison function, your initial list is already sorted.

Comment: ... And what if a[1] == b[0] AND a[0] == b[1]? What if neither is the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure your comparison function is a valid one in a mathematical sense, i.e. transitive. Given `a, b, c` a comparison function saying that `a > b` and `b > c` implies that `a > c`. Sorting procedures rely on this property.

Not to mention that by your rules, for `a = [1, 2]` and `b = [2, 1]` you have both `a[1] == b[0]` and `a[0] == b[1]` which means that *a is both greater and smaller than b*.

Comment: Sorry, I've not explained it very well. In my data set, not exists the case (1,2) and (2,1) at the same time. Really the numbers are state id's, and the tuple is a transition representation, i.e. (2,3) means, state(2).next() == 3.

Comment: @Antonio: still, without "normal" behavior from the comparison function (such as transitivity) you cannot expect the sort to work properly

Comment: You're right. I'm reviewing all the problem. A lot of thanks.

Answer (score 15):

Sounds a lot to me you are trying to solve one of the Google's Python class problems, which is to sort a list of tuples in increasing order based on their last element.

This how I did it:

```
def sort_last(tuples):

  def last_value_tuple(t):
    return t[-1]

  return sorted(tuples, key=last_value_tuple)
```

EDIT: I didn't read the whole thing, and I assumed it was based on the last element of the tuple. Well, still I'm going to leave it here because it can be useful to anyone.

Answer (score 7):

You could also write your code using *lambda*

```
def sort(tuples):
  return sorted (tuples,key=lambda last : last[-1])
```

so sort([(1, 3), (3, 2), (2, 1)]) would yield [(2, 1), (3, 2), (1, 3)]

Answer (score 4):

You can write your own custom key function to specify the key value for sorting.

Ex.

```
def sort_last(tuples):

    return sorted(tuples, key=last)

def last(a):
    return a[-1]
```

tuples => sorted tuple by last element

- `[(1, 3), (3, 2), (2, 1)]` => `[(2, 1), (3, 2), (1, 3)]`
- `[(1, 7), (1, 3), (3, 4, 5), (2, 2)]` => `[(2, 2), (1, 3), (3, 4, 5), (1, 7)]`

Answer (score 0):

Your ordering specification is wrong because it is not [transitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation).

Transitivity means that if `a < b` and `b < c`, then `a < c`. However, in your case:

```
(1,2) < (2,3)
(2,3) < (3,1)
(3,1) < (1,2)
```

Comment: well, really (1,2) < (2,3), and yes, the problem is about graphs, and this a cycle. Really in my dataset doesn't exists cycles. Anyway, you are right :)

Comment: @Antonio Beamud Oh, I switched < and > from your example. Corrected. However, comparison functions **must** be transitive, because that allows the sorting routine to take shortcuts (like compare a,b and b,c and never a,c). The cycle is just used for proving that your comparison function is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Try `lt.sort(tcmp, reverse=True)`.

(While this may produce the right answer, there may be other problems with your comparison method)