# I have a list contains string and float numbers, how to sort number by descending order and print the list to standard output

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list below:

```
mylist = [('Jim', 0.745), ('James', 0.812), ('Charlie', 0.752), ('Henry', 0.694), ('Minnie', 0.693), (None,)]
```

and I would like to sort order by the number and return to:

```
my_list = [('James', 0.812), ('Charlie', 0.752), ('Jim', 0.745), ('Henry', 0.694), ('Minnie', 0.693), (None,)]
```

and print my_list as standard output:

```
james 0.812
Charlie 0.752
Jim 0.745
Henry 0.694
Minnie 0.693
None
```

I have tried to sort by following:

```
my_list = sorted(mylist, key=lambda x:(x[1]), reverse=True)
```

But it shows `TupleError: tuple index out of range`

what should I do to correct for just use list comprehension to do another loop to achieve it? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sorting tuples in python with a custom key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554115/sorting-tuples-in-python-with-a-custom-key)

Comment: Your last tuple only has one value

Comment: use exception handling in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include length of tuple in your sorting logic.

The main point is your `lambda` can return a tuple, which Python naturally sorts sequentially. Then you can `print` via a simple `for` loop.

```
res = sorted(mylist, key=lambda x: (-len(x), -x[1] if len(x) > 1 else float('-inf')))

for i in res:
    print(' '.join(list(map(str, i))))
```

Result:

```
James 0.812
Charlie 0.752
Jim 0.745
Henry 0.694
Minnie 0.693
None
```

---

Inspired by juanpa.arrivillaga, a `try` / `except` clause is a good option for handling infrequent exceptions:

```
def sorter(x):
    try:
        return x[1]
    except IndexError:
        return float('-inf')

res = sorted(mylist, key=sorter, reverse=True)
```

Comment: Thanks jpp, perfect answer. Then how can I get the desire standard output?

Comment: I included the `for` loop you need with `print`. Run that and you should see the result you want.

Comment: perfect jpp, thank you so much~~~learn a lot from the try/except clause ^_^

Comment: better to return `float('-inf')` rather than `0` if you really want it to sort to the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Your last tuple does not have two elements. Use a custom key function:

```
def key(item):
    if len(item) == 2:
        return item[1]
    else:
        return 0

sorted(mylist, key=key, reverse=True)
```

Output:

```
[('James', 0.812), ('Charlie', 0.752), ('Jim', 0.745), ('Henry', 0.694), ('Minnie', 0.693), (None,)]
```

Comment: lutz, I have tried the code but somehow it returns the same error as before.